# When restarting delayed_job with capistrano it isn't always creating the pid file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, delayed-job

When sshing into the webserver I can restart delayed_job all day without a problem.  It brings down the existing worker, starts a new one and writes tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid with its process id.  (I am also restarting passenger to mimic what I'm about to do with capistrano)

```
app@StagingServer:/app/current$ touch tmp/restart.txt; RAILS_ENV=staging script/delayed_job restart
delayed_job: trying to stop process with pid 22170...
delayed_job: process with pid 22170 successfully stopped.
delayed_job: process with pid 22284 started.
app@StagingServer:/app/current$ touch tmp/restart.txt; RAILS_ENV=staging script/delayed_job restart
delayed_job: trying to stop process with pid 22284...
delayed_job: process with pid 22284 successfully stopped.
delayed_job: process with pid 22355 started.
app@StagingServer:/app/current$ touch tmp/restart.txt; RAILS_ENV=staging script/delayed_job restart
delayed_job: trying to stop process with pid 22355...
delayed_job: process with pid 22355 successfully stopped.
delayed_job: process with pid 22427 started.
app@StagingServer:/app/current$
```

However, when I deploy using capistrano

```
dev@ubuntu:~/app-site$ cap passenger:restart
    triggering start callbacks for `passenger:restart'
  * executing `multistage:ensure'
*** Defaulting to `staging'
  * executing `staging'
  * executing `passenger:restart'
  * executing "touch /app/current/tmp/restart.txt"
    servers: ["staging.app.com"]
    [staging.app.com] executing command
    command finished in 242ms
  * executing "cd /app/current;RAILS_ENV=staging script/delayed_job restart"
    servers: ["staging.app.com"]
    [staging.app.com] executing command
 ** [out :: staging.app.com] delayed_job: trying to stop process with pid 21646...
 ** [out :: staging.app.com] delayed_job: process with pid 21646 successfully stopped.
    command finished in 11889ms
```

Seems fine? While the last line from delayed_job isn't printed (I think due to it not ending in a newline) this does successfully create a new process.  However, **it doesn't create the .pid file**, so when I try and restart again:

```
dev@ubuntu:~/app-site$ cap passenger:restart
    triggering start callbacks for `passenger:restart'
  * executing `multistage:ensure'
*** Defaulting to `staging'
  * executing `staging'
  * executing `passenger:restart'
  * executing "touch /app/current/tmp/restart.txt"
    servers: ["staging.app.com"]
    [staging.app.com] executing command
    command finished in 398ms
  * executing "cd /app/current;RAILS_ENV=staging script/delayed_job restart"
    servers: ["staging.app.com"]
    [staging.app.com] executing command
 ** [out :: staging.app.com] Warning: no instances running. Starting...
 ** [out :: staging.app.com] delayed_job: process with pid 21950 started.
    command finished in 6758ms
```

It doesn't stop the existing process.  Strangely, this time it will create a new process *and* it's .pid file.

This leaves me with 2 delayed_jobs processes running and only one in the .pid file. Every 2 cap deploys I do will add another delayed_job process. The previous processes are using the old version of the app, essentially breaking it.

config/deploy.rb:

```ruby
namespace :passenger do
  desc "Restart Application"  
  task :restart do  
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    run "cd #{current_path};RAILS_ENV=#{deploy_env} script/delayed_job restart"
  end
end
after :deploy, "passenger:restart"
```

- Ubuntu, nginx, passenger
- daemons (1.1.4)
- delayed_job (2.1.4)
- rails (3.0.9)

And locally

- capistrano (2.9.0)
- capistrano-ext (1.2.1)

**Update:**

Reading around, it seems it could be to do with a race condition inside daemons.  However I'm a bit confused why it's showing only (and consistently) when using capistrano.  I will try changing the command to a stop, sleep then start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by using stop and start instead of restart.  Works due to a race condition probably caused by the daemons gem.

I would still like to know if anyone else has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and stopping and starting didn't work for me, so I came up with the following:

```
namespace :delayed_job do
desc 'Restart delayed_job worker'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:delayed_job) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :pkill , "-f", "'delayed_job'"
          execute :bundle, :exec, "bin/delayed_job", :start
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
...
after :restart,  "delayed_job:restart"
```

Not a huge fan of the pkill, but this works consistently for me. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano shuffles a symlink for the current directory during each deployment which was orphaning the PID for me. We use the capistrano3-delayed-job gem which suggests applying one of these fixes to deploy.rb:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w(tmp/pids)

# or

set :delayed_job_pid_dir, '/tmp'
```

The first of which worked to resolve this issue for us. It moves the current/tmp/pids to shared/tmp/ and symlinks it in the current tree so that it persists across deployments.